# Most efficient way to compare data from different tables and add to a third

Tags: c#, sql

**The Problem**

I have three tables, lets say 'Table One' 'Table Two' and 'Table Three'.
All three have a different schema, however, Table One and Table Two have one matching column.

Table One is currently 50,000 rows. Table Two is 5,000 but will increase.
For each row in Table Two, I need to check if column B is ever equal to Column B in Table One. If it is I need the Column A value.

**What I've done**

Initially when the tables weren't so big I had a nested loop checking the values

```
foreach(DataRow r in TableOne)
{
  foreach(DataRow s in TableTwo)
  {
    if(r.ItemArray[1] == s.ItemArray[1])
       doSomethingWith(r.ItemArray[0]);
  }
}
```

However, I feel this is only going to become a big recourse issue as the table size increase.

I considered the following, but am not sure if there's a better way to future proof myself further:

```
SELECT TableOne.ColumnB, TableTwo.ColumnB, TableOne.ColumnA
FROM TableOne
LEFT JOIN ColumnA on TableOne.ColumnB = TableTwo.ColumnB
```

**Edit**
To be more clear - this is occurring in a c# application, not on the server side.

Comment: Are you using linq??  Also, let me know which sql version you are using

Comment: 1. Are you fine with doing this in SQL Server instead of c#?
2. What is the DBMS? because sql is not..

Comment: Also, it would be good if you directly handle this on sql side rather than making round trips between data layer and business logic.

Comment: Dirty Developer - I've never used linq, but I'm not opposed to the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For each row in Table Two, I need to check if column B is ever equal to Column B in Table One. If it is I need the Column A value.

```
SELECT TableOne.ColumnB, TableTwo.ColumnB, TableOne.ColumnA
FROM TableOne
JOIN TableTwo on TableOne.ColumnB = TableTwo.ColumnB
```

1. `JOIN` will give you those rows where `ColumnB` is equal in both `TableOne` and `TableTwo`.
2. `LEFT JOIN` will give you everything in item 1 above plus all the rows which did not match from `TableOne`.
3. `FULL JOIN` will give you 1 and 2 above plus all the rows which did not match from `TableTwo`.

You need number 1 above.

If there are a lot of rows, you do not want to do this in a loop in the application because to do that, you need to pull all the data from the database into the application memory and then do the filtering. If you have 500 rows in TableOne and 500 rows in TableTwo, you would pull 1000 rows into memory. If no match is found, you pulled all those rows for no good reason. If you do it on the database side, it will return 0 rows.

You can also do this using Linq to SQL:

```
from one in TableOne
join two in TableTwo on one.ColumnB equals two.ColumnB
select new { OneColumnB = one.ColumnB, TwoColumnB = two.ColumnB, ColumnA = one.ColumnA };
```

This Linq to SQL will generate the SQL query for you and the joining will occur on the SQL Server database side so your application will not take a penalty.

Comment: Ensure that ColumnB is indexed for both tables.  Also, you may want to create a view or Store Proc to call from C# to make for more efficient queries.

Comment: What would be the down side if ColumnB was not indexed?

Comment: Seen your edit - thanks for the explanation of the whole left join thing.

Comment: If the columns are not indexed SQL has to do table scans on each table to do the join; this gets very expensive as your table sizes increase.

Comment: Just added this all in and it works very well. I'll move it serve side when I get the chance. Thanks for your help.